# Get the hierarchical Category and keywords in TOM.NET

Tags: 2013, tom.net, taxonomy

I have Location category and under this category: region->countries->cities.I want to get the hierarchical category data in XML in TOM.NET by passing parent's categoryID.
I just want basic info e.g. tcmId , Title

I am trying below code :

```
TaxonomiesOwlFilter filter = new TaxonomiesOwlFilter(Engine.GetSession());
filter.RootCategories = new Category[] { new Category(Engine.GetSession(), 
                                                      new TcmUri("tcm:xx-xxxx-xxx")) };
Repository rep = this.Publication as  Repository;

Package.AddXml("Keywordxml", rep.GetTaxonomiesOwl(filter).ToString());
```

But while executing the code, I am getting the below error:

> "Invalid type:Category."

I really don't know how to do that, just trying solution found on sites.
Please let me know.

Comment: Is the category you are passing a root category (that is; it does not have any parents)?

Comment: yes , I am passing root category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks okay but I think you should use "OuterXml" or "InnerXml" in-place of "ToString", when adding the xml to package.

So the code will be `rep.GetTaxonomiesOwl(filter).OuterXml` inplace of `rep.GetTaxonomiesOwl(filter).ToString()`.

Well, rep.GetTaxonomiesOwl(filter) return a object of type `System.Xml.XmlElement`. So if you use ToString() method, it will just returns a string that represents the XmlElement object.

**Update:**

Why are you creating a "New" category object? please get the category using engine.GetObject() and use it in filter. 
I am assuming, you get the right publication in `Repository rep = this.Publication as Repository`.

Here is the code. I did not run it but I guess it should work:

```
TaxonomiesOwlFilter filter = new TaxonomiesOwlFilter(engine.GetSession());
Category cat = engine.GetObject(new TcmUri("tcm:xxx-xxxxx-xxx")) as Category;
filter.RootCategories = new Category[] { cat };
Repository rep = this.Publication as Repository;
package.PushItem("Keywordxml", package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(ContentType.Xml, rep.GetTaxonomiesOwl(filter).OwnerDocument));
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh Outerxml is also return string but problem is I am getting error in above code.
"Invalid type:Category." I think something releated to "Repository". Let me know if you have any views

Comment: well, both returns the string but [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) retruns a string representing the object. But OuterXml returns the xml as string.

Comment: I've run Saurabh's code (with a different TCMID of course) and it works fine except for this.Publication (which I replaced with engine.GetObject("tcm:0-1-1"); if the exact same code does not work I would try next with a new category with only a few keywords to isolate the problem

Comment: Saurabh , Code is working fine and give me hierarchical result as expected. Thanks.
One more thing using this  when we get the keyword detail , it contain the Metadata info but which meta schema attached to keyword is missing like schema name or href.
Can we do get that info too along with the same result ?

Comment: Please go through the API document and post a new question if you unable to get help from the document.